# Are prepared statements cached server-side across multiple page loads with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I learnt about prepared statements when making a JDBC-enabled Java application, and my app uses a connection pooling layer that assures me that prepared statements are cached server-side and this gives a performance benefit.

However, with PHP everything I've read says that they are only cached for the life of the page load. Generally I don't repeat the same query many times, but run several different queries, on a given page load, but will repeat them across multiple page loads.

As my PHP processes are persistent (i.e. they will serve hundreds of pages in their lifetime instead of just one, using PHP-FPM), I was wondering if they will re-use database connections, rather than spawning and killing them off for each hit.

1. Will using PHP-FPM with mysqli or PDO keep connections longer than a single page load?
2. If it doesn't, can I make it?
3. If it does, or I do #2, will this persist the caching of prepared statements longer than just one page load?

Edit:

Just to clarify, I'm not talking about the query cache, which is another beast entirely, or caching the output of queries. I want to cache the compiled prepared statement and its execution plan server-side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a request is served php "cleans" the instance and frees resources and other variables. This is done in several steps. Since fastcgi keeps the process alive after a request not all steps are executed and not all memory is freed. There is e.g. EG(persistent_list) which is used by [mysql_pconnect()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_pconnect), [pg_pconnect()](http://docs.php.net/pg_pconnect), ... This list isn't emptied between requests as long as the process keeps alive (could be, depending on the actual implementation, but that would defy the purpose of EG(persistent_list)). If you use persistent connections your script might get a "re-used" connection established during a previous request.
To (re-)use a prepared statement directly you need the identifier for that statement (and that connection). When using (php-)postgresql this is simply a (connection-wise) unique string you pass to [pg_execute()](http://docs.php.net/pg_execute), so your script has no problem to gain access to the statement previously prepared by another instance (using the same connection).
Using [mysqli](http://docs.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO-mysql](http://docs.php.net/pdo) you need a resource/object as statement identifier. That's kind of a problem since neither the mysqli nor the pdo extension seem to offer a way of storing the resource in EG(persist_list) between requests and you can't recreate it either. Unless php-fpm offers such a "service" it's seems impossible to re-use a mysql prepared statement directly.
All you can hope for is MySQL's [server-side query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html). In recent versions (see link) it may recognize the statement when using prepared statements. But even then it doesn't re-use the actual prepared statement:

> For a prepared statement executed via the binary protocol, comparison with statements in the query cache *is based on the text of the statement after expansion of ? parameter markers*. The statement is compared only with other cached statements that were executed via the binary protocol. That is, for query cache purposes, statements issued via the binary protocol are distinct from statements issued via the text protocol.

So, if I'm not mistaken, currently you can't re-use a mysql statement prepared during a previous request in php.

Comment: If I was using postgresql, would preparing a statement that has already been prepared automatically access the statement previously prepared, or would I have to do some magic to detect if the statement had been prepared already? I would be willing to switch away from MySQL for this.

Comment: The statement identifier you pass to pq_prepare() has to be unique for each single connection. I.e. if the second (or Nth) instance of the script tries to prepare the statement again with the same name a specific error will occur. Your script can handle that error code and assume that the (right) statement has already been prepared and is ready-to-use. It's still a little overhead and you might want to benchmark the net-effect you can expect before investing too much afford.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing what is happening at the PHP/Java tier with what's happenning in the database.

Yes, using prepared statements (usually) means that the execution plan is cached by the database itself (NOT the PHP/Java tier). However it does not follow that this always results in better performance - and an explanation of this would take several hundred pages. However I infer from what you've said elsewhere you are using MySQL as the DBMS which makes the discussion somewhat simpler (IIRC none of the storage engines implement histograms). Typically MySQL will be able to cache enough information about a schema to be able to generate a plan without any disk I/O. OTOH, using prepared statements mean a minimum of three round trips to the DBMS for each query (present statement, present params, retrieve results) while using inlined values eliminates on of these round trips. In the absence of histogram indexes, the value of the variables is irrelevant to the optimal plan detectable by the optimizer.

The fact that you are using PHP, or PHP-FPM or Java with single or persistent or pooled connections is irrelevant to whether or not prepared-statements are cached/re-used by the DBMS.

HTH

C.

Comment: Note PHP-FPM does not ake PHP behave like a java app server. The user data structures are still destroyed at the end of each request. But this is still irrelevant to statement caching.

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP application uses connection pooling to the database, and the database caches prepared statements, then yes, the caching will persist between pages. If the prepared statement caching is done by the client library, then this is more nebulous.

You need to look at the docs for PHP-FPM and/or PDO to see how to tell them to use connection pooling. There should be an option in both to do it.

You should be aware that MySQL connection setup and teardown is actually very fast and many PHP installations do not use connection pooling because of this. Either way, you should also invest time in your server settings, particularly the `wait_timeout` parameter. PHP is also designed around the idea that you create everything you need when your pages starts and it all goes away when the page finishes. Most PHP code and libraries assume this is the case. It is quite a different paradigm than under Java.

Comment: Should I be using PDO and not mysqli then?

Comment: The two offer slightly different APIs; it is not a simple case of either/or. I, personally, would use mysqli, but then that's because I have my own handler that extends mysqli the way I want.

Answer (score 2):

The only true answer is **it depends**.

Prepared statements are finicky beasts when it comes to MySQL. There are a great number of factors that determine whether or not a prepared statement is cached.

The general idea is if your version is < 5.1.17, the prepared statement is *never* cached in the query cache, and if using >= 5.1.17, **it depends**.

Please see the following page in the MySQL 5.1 manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html

Answer (score 2):

you can force mysqli to create a persistent connection by prepending p: to the hostname, as per the php doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

However, prepared statements are always closed between page loads, as discussed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/apis-php-mysqli.persistconns.html

Sorry, it can't be done as far as I know. Prepared statements are for a single page load.

Comment: Just to be a pedant... You need to prepend `p:` not append

Answer (score -1):

Prepared statements have nothing to do with result caching.

Result caching can be controlled via db server configuration or forced via memcached and the like.

I suggest you look into [memcached](http://memcached.org/), especially for PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Comment: I'm looking for the query caching prepared statements can get. Compiling the statements and caching the "execution plan" (correct term please?) is very much a benefit that prepared statements can give.

I already use memcached for result caching and it is indeed fantastic!

Answer (score -1):

PHP does not cache queries nor query results in most cases.  MySQL will perform this kind of caching regardless or what thread or connection is issuing the query.

If you want server-side caching across multiple page loads or multiple servers, then use MySQL query caching and server-side caching (APC, file-based caching, memcached, etc).