# PDO Prepared Statements - cross page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my page A.php , I prepare a query like this : `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?`

And I can use same PDO Prepared statements in this page , that I know.

But , if other page B.php also need the same query .

Am I need to prepared that query again?

Or how can I use the same PDO Prepared statements.

Or when I prepare the same query , server will auto know that was prepared?

---

Situation:

If i have a database website , then there are hundreds of pages load data just like the same way.

When user open each page , the query will send every times.

How can I build the page more wisely?

---

I am not looking for use the same "STRING" of query ;

I mean it is prepared statements , that I don't use $PDO->prepare again.

Is it possible?

Comment: You will either need to add that query to `B.php`, or place the query in a separate file, ie. `includes.php`, and include it in both `A.php` and `B.php`.

Comment: But how can I pass the last Prepared statements ?

Comment: Do you understand how PHPs processing model works? Each request starts without any allocated resources and prior variables. How would you imagine/go about reusing a prepared $statement/handle/object between A.php and B.php?

Comment: You didn't need to say that, you can just say : yes , you need to prepare it every page.
I just image a way to storage the prepared statement.

Comment: i just wondering what the PDO Prepared statements can do. or it was seem to waste the resource.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039416/are-prepared-statements-cached-server-side-across-multiple-page-loads-with-php

Comment: This link is more helpful

Answer (score 1):

By definition PHP scripts are standalone. So when you load `A.php` you have to connect to the DB and run your queries. When `A.php` is done processing, PHP will close the connection.

When you load `B.php` you will have to do the same thing

Comment: So , PDO Prepared statements can't cross page use ?

Comment: No. You can reuse the query via includes but prepared statements require an open connection to your DB

Comment: I edited the situation about my website, is there have a solve method? Or that just the only way to prepare query every page?

Comment: You'll have to prepare it every time. Prepared statements connect once to parse the query and a second time to pass the data